# Outgoing call muted after recording audio on Android with AudioRecord class

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

While recording audio on Android with the AudioRecord class there is an issue when I place an outgoing phone call. Even when the audio recording is stopped upon the "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" broadcast the outgoing audio stream is 'muted' (muted but now shown as muted) and the telephonee cannot hear me.
Does anybody know if this is a device specific issue (HTC Desire) oder firmware based issue? How could this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely firmware issue. I mean I got this problem only on Desire + CM7. Other combinations worked just OK.